# My object didnt "dash" on a new Input system. I have put in a code but didn't work

Tags: unity, c#

```
  [SerializeField] float baseSpeed = 5f;
float newSpeed;

public float DashPower;
public float DashTime;

bool isDashing = false;

Vector2 moveInput;
Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    newSpeed = baseSpeed;
}

void Update()
{
    Run();
}

void OnMove(InputValue value)
{
    moveInput = value.Get<Vector2>();
}    

void OnDash(InputValue value)
{
    if(value.isPressed)
    {
        if(!isDashing)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Dash());
        }
    }
}

void Run()
{
    Vector2 playerVelocity = new Vector2(moveInput.x, moveInput.y) * baseSpeed;
    rb.velocity = playerVelocity;
}

IEnumerator Dash()
{
    isDashing = true;
    newSpeed *= DashPower;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(DashTime);

    newSpeed = baseSpeed;
    isDashing = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Dash()` coroutine modifies `newSpeed`.

```
newSpeed *= DashPower;
...
newSpeed = baseSpeed;
```

Your `Update()` method calls `Run()`, and `Run()` scales the movement with `baseSpeed`, not `newSpeed`:

```
Vector2 playerVelocity = new Vector2(moveInput.x, moveInput.y) * baseSpeed;
```

So: you're applying the dash to a variable that you never use. This has nothing to do with the New Input System, you just need to write code that actually uses the variable you're modifying.